# transpose multiple columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
       AD    AP    AR     MD        MS     iS    AS
0    169.88  0.00  50.50  814.0    57.3    32.3  43.230
1     12.54  0.01  84.75   93.0    51.3    36.6  43.850
2    321.38  0.00  65.08  986.0    56.7    28.9  42.070
```

I would like to change the dataframe above to a transposed version where for each column, the values are put in a single row, so e.g. for columns `AD` and `AP`, it will look like this

```
d1_AD   d2_AD  d3_AD     d1_AP     d2_AP    d3_AP
169.88  12.54  321.38    0.00      0.01     0.00
```

I can do a transpose, but how do I get the column names and output structure like above?

NOTE: The output is truncated for legibility but the actual output should include all the other columns like `AR     MD        MS     iS    AS`

Comment: is the output truncated? where are MD, MS, is, AS, ...?

Comment: @sammywemmy, yes I truncated the output for legibility

Comment: Regardless of how many rows it should always become 1 rows?

Comment: ok, fair, however, it would make sense/ clearer if you loaded the entire output, to avoid confusion

Comment: @HenryEcker, yes regardless of number of rows, it should always become 1 row

Comment: ummmm why you need the format like this , just try stack or maybe unstack ? leave the multiple index there will easy for you to convert back

Comment: @BENY this is to feed into a machine learning algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to make the index of the correct form, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), then Collapse the MultiIndex and [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

```
new_df = df.rename(lambda x: f'd{x + 1}').stack().sort_index(level=1)
new_df.index = new_df.index.map('_'.join)
new_df = new_df.to_frame().transpose()
```

Input `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AD': [169.88, 12.54, 321.38], 'AP': [0.0, 0.01, 0.0],
    'AR': [50.5, 84.75, 65.08], 'MD': [814.0, 93.0, 986.0],
    'MS': [57.3, 51.3, 56.7], 'iS': [32.3, 36.6, 28.9],
    'AS': [43.23, 43.85, 42.07]
})
```

`new_df`:

```
    d1_AD  d2_AD   d3_AD  d1_AP  d2_AP  ...  d2_MS  d3_MS  d1_iS  d2_iS  d3_iS
0  169.88  12.54  321.38    0.0   0.01  ...   51.3   56.7   32.3   36.6   28.9

[1 rows x 21 columns]
```

---

If lexicographic sorting does not work we can wait to convert the MultiIndex to string until after `sort_index`:

```
new_df = df.stack().sort_index(level=1)  # Sort level 1 (by number)
new_df.index = new_df.index.map(lambda x: f'd{x[0]+1}_{x[1]}')
new_df = new_df.to_frame().transpose()
```

Larger frame:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 4, ignore_index=True)
```

Truncated output:

```
    d1_AD  d2_AD   d3_AD   d4_AD  d5_AD  ...  d8_iS  d9_iS  d10_iS  d11_iS  d12_iS
0  169.88  12.54  321.38  169.88  12.54  ...   36.6   28.9    32.3    36.6    28.9

[1 rows x 84 columns]
```

---

If needing columns in same order as `df`, use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) using `ignore_index=False` to not have to recalculate groups and let `melt` handle the ordering:

```
new_df = df.melt(value_name=0, ignore_index=False)
new_df = new_df[[0]].set_axis(
    # Create the new index
    'd' + (new_df.index + 1).astype(str) + '_' + new_df['variable']
).transpose()
```

Truncated output on the larger frame:

```
    d1_AD  d2_AD   d3_AD   d4_AD  d5_AD  ...  d8_AS  d9_AS  d10_AS  d11_AS  d12_AS
0  169.88  12.54  321.38  169.88  12.54  ...  43.85  42.07   43.23   43.85   42.07

[1 rows x 84 columns]
```

Comment: thanks @Henry, when I run your soln, the output header becomes `d1_AD  d10_AD ..` instead of `d1_AD d2_AD ...`

Comment: That's lexicographic ordering. We can do a few things to fix that let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `melt` and `set_index` with `groupby`:

```
x = df.melt().set_index('variable').rename_axis(index=None).T.set_axis([0])
x.set_axis(x.columns + x.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).transform('cumcount').add(1).astype(str), axis=1)
```

---

```
      AD1    AD2     AD3  AP1   AP2  AP3   AR1    AR2    AR3  ...   MS1   MS2   MS3   iS1   iS2   iS3    AS1    AS2    AS3
0  169.88  12.54  321.38  0.0  0.01  0.0  50.5  84.75  65.08  ...  57.3  51.3  56.7  32.3  36.6  28.9  43.23  43.85  42.07

[1 rows x 21 columns]
```